# php array. cant get the output i desire. help me

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this code

```
$dir = "img/ori/";  
$dir_thumbs = "img/thumbs/";

$images = array();  
$d = dir($dir);  
while($name = $d->read()){  
    $thumb = "thumb_".$name;  
    $images[] = array('name' => $name,'thumb_url' => $dir_thumbs.$thumb);  
}  
$d->close();  
$o = array('images'=>$images);
```

i want to output $name and $thumb_url of all the images. how to do it.? help me

Comment: (little off topic note : *!preg_match('/\.(jpg|gif|png)* isn't enough for security if this is like an upload script. )

Comment: And what is the output you desire exactly?

Comment: @Eray interesting. Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: i want to output $name and $thumb_url separate.. 

like echo $name . $thumb_url;

Comment: try echo json_encode($o); << you will get the idea.

i want only to output $name and $thumb_url.

Comment: @Dogbert , for example if this is an upload script, user can be upload any file which has a name like **image.png.cmd** or **image.cmd.png**

Comment: @Eray, I don't think so? the regex uses $ at the end..?

Comment: @Eray, atleast not `image.png.cmd`

Comment: image.cmd.png ? .png at the end of the file name , but actually it's not a PNG file. It's just a basically example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "{$image['name']} {$image['thumb_url']}";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for this:

```
print_r($o);
//or
var_dump($o);
```

Comment: actualy i wanted to verify it like this..
if ($name = $thumb) {
do something;
}

Comment: i want to output both the $name and $thumbs different.. 

like echo $name .'&nbsp;'.$thumb_url;

thanks for the quick response